# How to stub dependencies in unit tests when using TypeScript and Sinon

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, mocha.js, tdd, sinon

I am using TypeScript to build a Koa REST API and I'm using a dependency injection library called Awilix to make unit testing simpler.

If I wasn't using TypeScript, I would write my unit tests thus:

```js
  // setup
  const userService = {
    getUserById: sinon.stub(),
  };
  const userController = factory(userService);

  // example test
  it('works', () => {
    userController();
    expect(userService.getUserById).to.have.been.called();
  });
```

As the userService interface has more methods than just `getUserById` though, when you use TypeScript, I get errors like:

`Property 'insert' is missing in type '{ getUserById: SinonStub<any[], any>; }' but required in type 'UserServiceInterface'.`

Is there a way of getting around this without having to stub out every single method of a dependency?

Thanks

Comment: `const userService: any = {...}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe the interface for the userService is stricter than that though. That would result in the same error above

Comment: ^ @jshjohnson I tried this case using `any` and didn't get the error

Comment: This might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-sinon

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sinon.createStubInstance(MyConstructor, overrides)](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) method to create a new object with the given functions as the prototype and stubs all implemented functions.

E.g.

`userService.ts`:

```
export interface IUserService {
  getUserById(id: string): Promise<any>;
  insert(data: any): any;
}

export class UserService implements IUserService {
  async getUserById(id: string): Promise<any> {
    throw new Error('not implementated');
  }
  insert(data: any): any {
    throw new Error('not implementated');
  }
}
```

`userController.ts`:

```
import { IUserService } from './userService';

export function factory(userService: IUserService) {
  return async function userController() {
    return userService.getUserById('1');
  };
}
```

`userController.test.ts`:

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { factory } from './userController';
import { UserService } from './userService';

// const userService = {
//   getUserById: sinon.stub(),
// };
const userService = sinon.createStubInstance(UserService);
const userController = factory(userService);

describe('57716288', () => {
  it('works', () => {
    userController();
    sinon.assert.called(userService.getUserById);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  57716288
    ✓ works


  1 passing (4ms)
```